# Windows 8 App Login from Microsoft Account and App account

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-live-id, microsoft-account

I want to develop a Windows 8 app that uses Microsoft Account to enable synchronization between devices.

However, the user must also log-in through a web service to use the App.

How does it work then? Can the log-in be "associated" to a Microsoft Account across devices?

Is there a tutorial/link explaining how to do this?

I hope I was clear.

Comment: I am pretty sure that a Microsoft Account supports OAuth 2.0.  Microsoft calls this service "Live Connect" its documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are syncing between different computers running the same Windows 8 app you can use the roaming settings and roaming folders

- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ApplicationData-sample-fb043eb2

The sample covers both local and roaming data.

if you are trying to sync between an Wwindows 8 app and a iOS app you could use SkyDrive with the live SDK

- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Live-SDK-Windows-Developer-8ad35141

from what I understand if you choose the roaming settings, windows will keep those settings up to date on each device, so that's what I would suggest.
Hope it helps